# What is the binary format of the OrCAD .OLB files?

Tags: schematics, library, orcad

I want to auto generate .OLB files for my own components, so I need to either use Orcad Capture scripting, or alternatively write the binary .OLB files myself.

Is there anybody that have seen a specification of the binary OrCAD .OLB file format ?

Sorry if this question is non-SO compliant... however, I have sometimes seen useful answers toeven non-SO compliant questions ;-)

Comment: Just curious, are you sure you need to do this? It sounds like you are doing some very unique things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about electrical engineering.

Comment: I'd wonder whether such a specification even exists outside of OrCAD's offices. It's likely OrCAD doesn't want to let people use their formats without buying their software.

Comment: @Tyler: It is very useful to automate generation of symbols for e.g. an FPGA based on the FPGA output pin file, since that eases update at pin change and reduces risk of bugs in schematic.

Comment: @Hearth:  OrCAD (Cadence) have not released the format, and guess they want to keep it proprietary.  For the question, I will surely delete it if it pollutes SO; just thought this may be the place with most experienced engineers for a question like that.

Answer (score 1):

Libraries can be exported to and imported from xml. With this and some Java coding should get you what you want without knowing the format. You could also reverse engineer the hex format from the xml. For large jobs, it's probably worth purchasing CIS. OLBs are very difficult to deal with in Capture.

Comment: Thanks a lot; I had not thought of import/export with XML, but that it a much better solution than trying to reverse engineer the binary OLB format, and scripting in Python (or probably Java that I don't know that well) can easily make XML files.

Comment: I just used the XML-to-OLB command twice, on the same library XML file, and got two binary-different OLB files. Yay, now "nothing changed" shows up as a "something changed" in version control.

Comment: I'm not sure how CIS helps matters. For schematic symbols, CIS stores paths to symbols in OLB files.